# How to know an subsequence of some sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Could someone explain to me why we have :

- $(u_{3.2^{n+1}})$ is Subsequence of $(u_{2n})$ and $(u_{3n})$ and $(u_{6n})$ and  $(u_{3.2^{n}})$
- $(u_{2^{n+1}})$ is Subsequence of $(u_{2n})$ and $(u_{2^{n}})$
- $(u_{3.2^{n}})$ is Subsequence of $(u_{3n})$
- $(u_{6n})$ is Subsequence of $(u_{2n})$ and $(u_{3n})$

Here is my thoughts:

1. an subsequence of $u_n$ is $u_{\phi(n)}$ with $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ Strictly increasing such that :

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad u_n=u_{\phi(n)}$$

2. An subsequence of $u_{\phi(n)}$ is $u_{ \varphi\circ \phi(n)}$ with $\phi:\mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{N}$ Strictly increasing such that :

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad u_{\phi(n)}=u_{\varphi\circ \phi(n)}$$

so for

- $(u_{6n})$ is Subsequence of $(u_{2n})$ with

$$\phi:\begin{cases}  \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\\ n\longmapsto 3n \end{cases}$$

- Am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Yes, you're right. That's precisely what should be shown.

> Let's consider the second part:
>
> - The sequence $(u_{2^{n+1}})$ is a subsequence of $(u_{2n})$ since we can represent $2^{n+1}$ as $$2^{n+1}=2m>2n$$
>     with $m=2^n$.
> - The sequence $(u_{2^{n+1}})$ is a subsequence of $(u_{2^n})$ since we can represent $2^{n+1}$ as $$2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n>2^n$$

The other examples can be shown similarly.

Comment: could you elaborate the others ?